# Get PHP INI File

Tags: php

Is there a way to use something like

```
ini_get_all()
```

And output to the screen what the .ini file actually looks like. I mean so you can copy and paste it. This is because I cannot actually access the hosts .ini but can make my own. But when I make my own it loses all of the current settings so I need to know how it is setup currently.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 This is the formatted ini content, not raw content.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
echo file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file());
```

You can also check if your php is loading any additional .ini file aside of the main php.ini.

```
//This will return you a comma separated list of the additional ini files loaded
    $additional_ini_files = php_ini_scanned_files();

    // The explode and the str_replace is for removing the new line char from the strings
    foreach(explode(",\n",$additional_ini_files) as $ini_file_path){ 

          echo file_get_contents(str_replace("\n","",$ini_file_path)); 

    }
```

Comment: I ran that and got a "About php.ini" long long message that doesnt seem to be the actuall ini

Comment: @Max maybe you use also other ini's, but this is clearly the right code.

Comment: @Max if you first run "echo php_ini_loaded_file();" it will return you the absolute path of the php.ini that is loaded. Check that first. Then file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file()); will return you the  content of the file. I tried locally and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Max, you can also check if your php is loading any extra .ini file with php_ini_scanned_files();